# AWS Default region not setting using env variable in boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Python terminal below

```
In [3]: os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
Out[3]: 'us-west-2'

In [4]: import boto

In [5]: boto.connect_ec2()
Out[5]: EC2Connection:ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

AWS Default region is not getting set even after using `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` as env variable. Please suggest !

Answer (score 5):

**Solution:**

`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` works only with `boto3`.
I was using `boto2`. Environment variables for region is not supported in `boto2`.

Updating the `boto.cfg` fixed the `problem`.